# Media record cordova is not releasing the file

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-media-plugin

Plugin media is not releasing the record. It saves a temporary file in the root directory of my device and doesn't create the file.

This is how a start recording:

```
var src = 'RaptorV4/Audio/Record.mp3';

App.mediaRec = new App.Media(src, function () {
            //ok
        }, function () {
            //failed
            if (!NODEWEBKIT) {
                App.alert('record failed for ' + App.currentRecfullPath);
            } else {
                App.alertify('error', 'record failed for ' + App.currentRecfullPath);
            }

            App.db.deleteFile(App.currentRecFullPath);
            App.stopRecAudio();
        }, function () {
            //changed
        });
App.mediaRec.startRecord();
```

And this is how I get the size of the file:

```
 App.mediaRec.stopRecord();
        App.mediaRec.release();

    var fileSize = $.Deferred();
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function (fs) {
        fs.getFile(fullPath, {create: false}, function (file) {
            file.file(function(f){fileSize.resolve(+f.size);return;});            
        });
    });

 $.when(fileSize).done(function(size){
        console.warn(size);
}
```

Size is always 0 and I think that is because of how I save and get the file.

Comment: Please show me your code ..How had you done this . Thanks

Comment: Post Edited. can you help me?

Comment: sure bro let me review your question again . Thanks for responding back

Answer (score 0):

you will have to add the Cordova File System Plugin first to create a new Entry.

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

To create the record File and set the global variables fileURL and audioRecord:

```
//Prepares File System for Audio Recording
audioRecord = 'record.wav';
onDeviceReady();

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(1, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(audioRecord, {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();
}
```

to start and stop the record:

```
 record = new Media(audioRecord,
            // success callback
            function () {
                console.log("recordAudio():Audio Succes: ");
            },

            // error callback
            function (err) {
                console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: " + err.code);
            });

        // Record audio
        record.startRecord();
        // Wait
        record.stopRecord();
```

Comment: Please review my answer if you have any issue comment down here now . Thanks

Comment: But my application files should be in the root directory of the device, with that change it would save in an android folders. The user must have easy access to the recording

Comment: For this I use cordova.file.externalRootDirectory as directory and window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL to get the directory. I think that this is the problem. Some conflicts in the directory

Comment: This will create the file in root of your device memory . I had tested it on my android device . Thanks